# Why the loop is replacing the treenode already pushed in vector

Tags: algorithm

I am having trouble understanding why the loop is replacing the root node already pushed in the vector.
Below was my code
vector<TreeNode*> generateAllBST(int start,int end)
{

```
    if(start>end)
    {
        vector<TreeNode*> v;
        v.push_back(NULL);
        return v;
    }
    vector<TreeNode*> v;
    for(int i=start;i<=end;i++)
    {
        TreeNode* root=new TreeNode(i,NULL,NULL);
        vector<TreeNode*> left=generateAllBST(start,i-1);
        vector<TreeNode*> right=generateAllBST(i+1,end);
        for(int j=0;j<left.size();j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<right.size();k++)
            {
                root->left=left[j];
                root->right=right[k];
                v.push_back(root);
            }
        }
    }
    return v;
}
```

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nBNIZ.png)

Comment: For every *i* you only create one `root` object, so what did you expect? If you want to push different objects, then you'll have to create `root` in the inner loop.

Comment: You should also tag this question with the appropriate language tag.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For a particular value of `i`, you only create one `root` object, which you then give varying `left` and `right` property values, and push each time to your vector again. But it's the same object (reference).

You seem to want to push different objects to your vector, so you need to create each of those objects. And so you need to move the assignment to `root` inside the inner most loop:

```
    for(int i=start;i<=end;i++)
    {
        vector<TreeNode*> left=generateAllBST(start,i-1);
        vector<TreeNode*> right=generateAllBST(i+1,end);
        for(int j=0;j<left.size();j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<right.size();k++)
            {
                TreeNode* root=new TreeNode(i,NULL,NULL); // <---
                root->left=left[j];
                root->right=right[k];
                v.push_back(root);
            }
        }
    }
```

And then you might use the other arguments of the constructor, like so:

```
    for(int i=start;i<=end;i++)
    {
        vector<TreeNode*> left=generateAllBST(start,i-1);
        vector<TreeNode*> right=generateAllBST(i+1,end);
        for(int j=0;j<left.size();j++)
        {
            for(int k=0;k<right.size();k++)
            {
                v.push_back(new TreeNode(i,left[j],right[k]));
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Yes, you are correct. Thanks, I made a mistake while constructing since all combinations will be new trees

Answer (score 0):

There was a very little flaw actually I was editing the right pointer and left pointer in loops so root node should also be initialized again in the loop to create a new BST